# How to show video title in Google analytics statistics report page

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics, jwplayer

Please let me know if there is any method to show a video title in Google analytics statistics report page other than just urls.

Is there a way to pass a video title name along with the ga-pro plugin parameters.

Need to get the below details in analytic account

1. WHICH VIDEO is being played and from WHICH DOMAINS that are hosting the player
2. Which sites are generating the most plays and clicks

Do I need to give video name and site url in id string parameter? Will this solve my issue?

As per the documentation

Configuration Option: `gapro.idstring = ||streamer||/||file|`|

Controls the string sent to Google Analytics to identify your video. May be set per playlist item or globally. You may use any property of a playlist (including custom properties in the JW namespace), surrounded by double pipes (e.g. - `||property||`). For a list of common properties

Can you explain me about "`streamer`" and "`file`" specified here.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set the `idstring` configuration parameter.

Click [Here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/addons/plugins/107/get-plugin.php?addon=107&vid=292) for more information on how to configure this.